# why the sub-side navigating bar not appearing when I click on the parent link

Tags: html, frontend, uinavigationbar, nav

what i am trying to do is when i click on the main link on the side navigation bar and it has sub navigation, it shows the sub navigations and also shifted down the other navigation bar. but what i am facing is once i click on the main link, it shows up the sub navigation bar on top the other main links. note: the other main links exist but it doesn't show up.

Html  code example

```
<li>
        <a href="#" id="3"> Sales <span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span> </a>
        <ul class="item-show-3">
            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">All Sales</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Invoices</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
```

in the js file to

```
  $('.sidebar ul li a').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('nav ul li ul.item-show-' + id).toggleClass("show");
            $('nav ul li #' + id + ' span').toggleClass("rotate");
            //$('nav ul ul ').css("position", "absolute");
        });
```

Css file

```
    nav ul ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
}

nav ul li ul.show {
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.5s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(' ul li a').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('ul li ul.item-show-' + id).toggleClass("show");
  $('ul li #' + id + ' span').toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

```css
ul ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
}

ul li ul.show {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.5s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="3"> Sales <span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span> </a>
    <ul class="item-show-3">
      <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All Sales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Invoices</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please try this after altering the selectors according to your actual code